# Set all columns to `null` in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a quick way to change all fields in a table that are null to just empty fields. I have many columns so wondered if there was a way to do it by table rather than column by column.

I need something like

```
update table 1 
set * = '' 
where * is null
```

but obviously this is incorrect syntax

Comment: Can you show us your schema as well, i.e. what are the columns? Or just roughly: do you have like 10 columns or 100? It may affect which solution should be chosen.

Comment: I gotta ask the obvious: why do you have so many columns? Usually when you have some many columns, it indicates you have a problem in your schema. If this is the case, you should just fix the schema problem.

Comment: because it is a large table in the database needed for the months of the years for the past 3 years

Comment: So are you telling that for each month/year pair there is a new column? Like `2011_12`, `2012_01`, `2012_02`, `2012_03`, etc.?

Comment: yes but that isn't relevant to the question. I'm not asking how to change schema as that is not up to me

Comment: I think its relevant as if you know the start month / end month, you could simply programmatically generate the column names for the set function. Otherwise you have to use some kind of introspection as suggested in the answers, which requires more SQL queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will generate update statements list, you have to only run it:

```
SELECT  'update '+ so.name+' set '+sc.name+'= '''' where '+sc.name+' is null '   
FROM sysobjects so
JOIN syscolumns sc ON so.id = sc.id
JOIN systypes st ON sc.xtype=st.xtype  
where so.type = 'U'
and st.name in('varchar','char')
--and so.name = 'tab' <--- if you need update only one table
```

[Here (sql fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6a09/2/0) you can see how it works.

Comment: But it will run an update for every column. In other words, if the table has 20 columns, it will run through the table 20 times(!!) with updates.

Comment: The OP stated in one of the comments that he needs to update much more than that!

Comment: This select geneate `update statement` list for all columns `varchar` and `char` in all tables. You can also use condition with table name. You have to only run this list.

Comment: On sql fiddle demo I added `and so.name = 'tab'` and it works, show you example pls.

Comment: SO when i run this and all the syntax appears, I can just copy and paste into the screen?

Comment: I removed a keyword `table`, you can try it again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate a script that will update all of the NULLable fields that contain NULLs to blanks, you can use the following code:

```
DECLARE @TAB VARCHAR(1000) = 'ProductVendor', 
        @COL VARCHAR(1000), 
        @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE UPDATE_CURSOR CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
  SELECT t2.NAME 
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM SYSOBJECTS 
           WHERE XTYPE = 'u' 
                 AND NAME = @TAB)T1 
         INNER JOIN SYSCOLUMNS t2 
                 ON T1.ID = t2.ID 
   WHERE t2.ISNULLABLE = 1 

OPEN UPDATE_CURSOR 

SET @SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @TAB + ' SET ' 

FETCH NEXT FROM UPDATE_CURSOR INTO @COL 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
      SET @SQL = @SQL + @COL + ' = Isnull(' + @COL + ', ''''),' 

      FETCH NEXT FROM UPDATE_CURSOR INTO @COL 
  END 

CLOSE UPDATE_CURSOR 

DEALLOCATE UPDATE_CURSOR 

SET @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, Len(@SQL) - 1) 

EXEC (@SQL)
```

All you need to do is change the table name at the beginning (the TAB variable).
The script generates a single query that will update all of the columns in one run.

Comment: Updated the answer. You can add as many fields as you want/need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeh i thought this was the only way. it will take a long time which is why i wanted a quick solution to do the whole table

Comment: Now it generates everything in one go. Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 
   SET ( COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ) = (SELECT COL1A, 
                                            COL2A, 
                                            COL3A, 
                                            COL4A 
                                       FROM TABLE2 
                                      WHERE COL5A = TABLE1.COL5) 
 WHERE COL5 IN (SELECT COL5A 
                  FROM TABLE2)
```

Answer (score -2):

try this please

```
 update table1 set columnnames='' where columnnames ='null'
```

Comment: if u have many fields give  the field names after the set separated by comma's